# Reduce double-quoting of variable containing spaces?

Tags: string, bash, file-io, escaping

I have a script like this:

```
file="results/semester1 (2013).csv"
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
  echo 'File exists.'

  # do more stuff with $file
fi
```

I want to do more stuff with `$file` inside the if block, like issue `mv`, `cp`, `ln`, etc. But I'm finding that each time I pass `$file` to these Unix commands, I have to encase it in double-quotes to deal with the space in the filename, otherwise I get errors. As you can see in the if condition, I'm already doing it once.

Is there any way to just double-quote it "once and for all" so I do not have to do it every single time?

Comment: Not a terribly practical answer, but switch to `zsh`. It does not perform word-splitting on parameter expansions by default, so you can safely leave them unquoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of, no. You'll need to quote that variable whenever you want it processed as a single value.

For tests specifically, you can avoid quoting it by using double brackets. Word splitting doesn't happen then. But that doesn't save you any typing.

```
if [[ -f $file ]] ; then
  ...
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way to just double-quote it "once and for all" so I do not have to do it every single time?

No. You **must** double-quote *every* usage of a variable (except for special cases, see Mat’s answer) which may contain spaces. There’s no way around it.

This is unusual and a bit annoying, but you get used to it pretty quickly.